# make iphone 6 app to fit iphone 4s screen resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-6

I have developed an app for iphone 6. It works well on iphone 5 also but on 4s the bottom part is being cut off. Is there any way i can make the app to work for iphone 4s without using autolayouts. 
This works well for iphone 6

[image]

But not for 4s, below is how it looks. The buttons are not visible.

[image]

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Add all the controls inside UIScrollview and not on UIVIew..

Comment: u can also use sizeclass .

Comment: this is what autolayouts are for though....

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UIScrollView`  instead of `UIView` & add all your inner control to Scroll view.

This will make Buttons visible all the time & Scroll the content.

Second Option, you can use AutoLayout. (which you dont want to use.!!)

Third , You can create a new design for iPhone 4s (if & only if u want the look exactly same as others) 
-although, not recommended!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIScrollView instead of UIView & add all your inner control to Scroll view. Otherwise use UITableView

It will solve your problem.